# Toggle modal popup from different buttons

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, popup

I am trying to get this popup open from different buttons in the menu, however, the popup content would remain the same.

Thanks, [Banick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15675139/banick)

```js
function OpenModalT() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModalT');
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

function CloseModalT() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModalT');
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="#" onclick="OpenModalT();">Button 1</a>

  <div id="myModalT" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close" onclick="CloseModalT();">&times;</span>
      <p>
        <ppopup>
          <br>
          <br>
          <strong>Dummy text Dummy text Dummy Text <br><br> Kind Regards
          </strong>
        </ppopup>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li>
  <a href="#" onclick="OpenModalT();">Button 2</a>
</li>
```

Comment: PS: Avoid using inline `on*` handlers same as you hopefully don't use inline `style` attributes- JS and CSS should be in one place only - and that's your files or tags.

Comment: Also, please install a better code editor. `”` is not quite `"`

Comment: `<ppopup>` is an invalid HTML5 tag.

Comment: Don't use `<a href="#">` if you need a button. Use `<button type="button">Click me</button>` instead.

Comment: Beyond @RokoC.Buljan 's list of bad practices, what is the actual problem?

Comment: You haven't started with the popup closed.

Comment: You need to add `display: none;` at the beginning.

Comment: @charlietfl I was wanting to have the same modal popup through anchor tags in a listing style menu. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example with which you can have any number of modals and buttons:

- Use modals with a unique ID
- Use `<button type="button" data-modal="#some-modal-id">` to toggle your modals

```js
const elsModals = document.querySelectorAll(".modal");

const toggleModal = (ev) => {
  const elBtn = ev.currentTarget;
  const elModal = document.querySelector(elBtn.dataset.modal);
  // Close all currently open modals:
  elsModals.forEach(el => {
    if (el !== elModal) el.classList.remove("is-active");
  });
  // Toggle open/close targeted one:
  elModal.classList.toggle("is-active");
};

const elsBtns = document.querySelectorAll("[data-modal]");
elsBtns.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", toggleModal));
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * {margin:0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100vw; height: 100vh;
  transition: 0.4s;
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.modal.is-active {
  pointer-events: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal-regards" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <button type="button" data-modal="#modal-regards" class="modal-close">&times;</button>
    <p>Dummy text Dummy text Dummy Text<br>Kind Regards</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="modal-help" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <button type="button" data-modal="#modal-help" class="modal-close">&times;</button>
    <p>If something is not clear,<br>feel free to ask.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" data-modal="#modal-regards">Kind regards</button>
<button type="button" data-modal="#modal-regards">Kind regards</button>
<button type="button" data-modal="#modal-help">Ask for help!</button>
```

Additionally:

- Avoid using inline on* handlers same as you hopefully don't use inline style attributes- JS and CSS should be in one place only - and that's your files or tags.
- Use a better code editor. `”` is not quite the same as `"` - such editor will mark and highlight those small typos.
- `<ppopup>` is an invalid HTML5 tag. – Roko C. Buljan 16 mins ago
- Don't use `<a href="#">` if you need a button. Use `<button type="button">` instead.

Comment: Hi Roko,

Thanks for your input, mate. A little bit on improvisation and the code works great. I have structured the menu with listing style as the website was built a bit old. I was wanting to use ul li and and triggering modals through onClick. However, there is a syntax error in the line:

const toggleModal = (ev) =>  {

Please suggest.

Many thanks :)

Comment: @Banick That's [ES6 syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Either target modern browsers. Or use Babel to transpile ES6 to ES5 (or build using Snowpack which uses the amazing [esbuild](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild) or Webpack)  - Or use just a better [code editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/) which will not argue about modern JS features.

Comment: What will be the change if I had to use href instead of a button? Thanks, I have to download the new editor anyway, guess its high time :|

Comment: `<a>` AKA: *Anchors* are links to pages. `<button>` instead are... exactly what it says: Buttons. Just remember to always use the `type="button"` attribute - since by default are `type="submit"`.

Comment: Thanks, Though I am not able to click anything under the modal placement. i've got a hero slider under the navbar.

Comment: @Banick remove the `pointer-events: none;` line

Comment: This didn't work so I tried changing the visibility: collapse; and it does the job

Comment: @Banick amazing found!

Comment: Hi @RokoCBuljan, hope you are well! I was able to run the script in the localhost but it shows me an error once I publish the project in the line underneath.

const toggleModal = (ev) => {

Do you know what could be the issue please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with `display: none`.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModalT');

function OpenModalT() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

function CloseModalT() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

function ModalFunction() {
  if (modal.style.display === "none") {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/*Add this:*/

#myModalT {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="#" onclick="ModalFunction();">Button 1</a>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModalT" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <p>
        <ppopup>
          <br>
          <br>
          <strong>Dummy text Dummy text Dummy Text <br><br> Kind Regards
          </strong>
          <span class="close" onclick="ModalFunction();">&times;</span>
        </ppopup>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li>
  <a href="#" onclick="ModalFunction();">Button 2</a>
</li>
```

**Added some features:**

1. You can click again to close
2. Saved Space in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You Should do better and simpler, with the use of a `<dialog>` element:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

```js
const
  e_Dialog  = document.querySelector('#dialog-element')
, e_Form_H4 = document.querySelector('#dialog-element > form > H4')
, Btns_Open = document.querySelectorAll('button.bt-open-Dialog')
  ;
Btns_Open.forEach( btn => btn.addEventListener('click', f_openDial ))
  ;
function f_openDial(evt)
  {
  e_Form_H4.textContent = 'open by button: ' + evt.target.textContent;
  e_Dialog.showModal();
  }
```

```css
dialog::backdrop { background: #0066ff40; }
button { width :  7em; display: block; margin: .4em; }
button.bt-open-Dialog::before { content : 'Button '; }
```

```html
<button class="bt-open-Dialog"> A </button>
<button class="bt-open-Dialog"> B </button>
<button class="bt-open-Dialog"> C </button>
<button class="bt-open-Dialog"> D </button>

<dialog id="dialog-element">
  <form method="dialog">
    <h4> h4 element</h4>
    <button>close <small>|| Esc</small></button>
  </form>
</dialog>
```