# Show clicked button's name in Modal window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to show the name of the button that was clicked inside a modal window body. I have tried to get the name of the button using `e.innerText` but I get `"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"`

I have not used `id` for the button as I do not want to use `id`

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing to show the name of the button clicked inside the modal body? Any help would be really helpful and highly appreciated.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("myModal")[0];

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btns = [...document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn")];

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btns.forEach(btn => btn.onclick = function showValue(elem) {
  $(".modal-body p").text(elem.innerText);
  modal.style.display = "block";
});

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function closePopup() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style: normal;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 0px 5px 10px;
  color: #333;
}

.errormodalbutton {
  background: none !important;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 !important;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  color: #069;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close-button {
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.close-button button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  float: right;
  font-family: Inter;
  font-style: normal;
  background: #6C757D;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="showValue(this)" class="myBtn errormodalbutton">Open Modal 1</button>
<hr>
<button onclick="showValue(this)" class="myBtn errormodalbutton">Open Modal 2</button>
<hr>
<button onclick="showValue(this)" class="myBtn errormodalbutton">Open Modal 3</button>
<hr>
<button onclick="showValue(this)" class="myBtn errormodalbutton">Open Modal 4</button>

<div class="myModal modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h3 style="text-align=center">Test</h3>
    <p></p>
    <div class="close-button">
      <button type="button" class="right" onclick="closePopup()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
add `jQuery library` to your code top

Comment: @MaheshThorat - Thank you. I added the ```<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>```. I can now see the modal window, but it does not show the text inside the body. Updated [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Unrigged/acfjLgwx/22/). Am I missing anything else?

Comment: In your JsFiddle, jquery was not referenced. It worked after adding a reference. Are you referencing it in your local code?

Comment: @Orifjon - Yes I was missing the jquery ref. I added the jquery link in the ```<script>``` tag. I can now see the modal window, but it does not show the text inside the body. It is blank. Updated [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Unrigged/acfjLgwx/23/). Am I missing anything else?

Comment: By using `var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("myModal")[0];` you're limiting yourself on having only one modal element per page - or run in the trouble of copy/pasting your JS logic to handle several such elements.

Comment: Inline HTML `onclick="showValue(this)"` should not be used. JS should be in one place only and that's your SCRIPT tag of file. Use `.addEventListener()` or jQuery's `.on()` method instead.

Comment: Tip: avoid over-commenting your code. Code should be always clean, logical, readable. Like a well written poem. (I removed unnecessary comments). Code should speak by itself.

Comment: Duplicate of [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67142639/383904) with the only difference that you need to just add: `elModal.querySelector(".someChild").textContent = elBtn.textContent;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`btns.forEach(btn => btn.onclick = function showValue(elem) {`
and
`$(".modal-body p").text(elem.innerText);`
are wrong.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("myModal")[0];

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btns = [...document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn")];

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal

function showValue(elem)
  {
  $(".modal p").text(elem.innerText);
  modal.style.display = "block";
  }

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function closePopup() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display          : none;                /* Hidden by default       */
  position         : fixed;               /* Stay in place           */
  z-index          : 1;                   /* Sit on top              */
  padding-top      : 100px;               /* Location of the box     */
  left             : 0;
  top              : 0;
  width            : 100%;                /* Full width              */
  height           : 100%;                /* Full height             */
  overflow         : auto;                /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color : rgb(0, 0, 0);        /* Fallback color          */
  background-color : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);  /* Black w/ opacity        */
  }
.modal-content {              /* Modal Content */
  font-family   : 'Inter';
  font-style    : normal;
  width         : 600px;
  height        : 200px;
  background    : #fff;
  border-radius : 6px;
  position      : absolute;
  top           : 50%;
  left          : 50%;
  transform     : translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align    : left;
  padding       : 0 0px 5px 10px;
  color         : #333;
  }
.errormodalbutton {
  background      : none !important;
  border          : none;
  padding         : 0 !important;
                                        /* optional */
  font-family     : arial, sans-serif;  /* input has OS specific font-family */
  color           : #069;
  text-decoration : underline;
  cursor          : pointer;
  }
.close-button {
  padding        : 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  vertical-align : baseline;
  }
.close-button button {
  position      : fixed;
  bottom        : 10px;
  right         : 10px;
  float         : right;
  font-family   : Inter;
  font-style    : normal;
  background    : #6C757D;
  color         : #fff;
  border        : 0;
  outline       : none;
  border-radius : 2px;
  cursor        : pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="showValue(this)" class="myBtn errormodalbutton">Open Modal 1</button>
<hr>
<button onclick="showValue(this)" class="myBtn errormodalbutton">Open Modal 2</button>
<hr>
<button onclick="showValue(this)" class="myBtn errormodalbutton">Open Modal 3</button>
<hr>
<button onclick="showValue(this)" class="myBtn errormodalbutton">Open Modal 4</button>

<div class="myModal modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h3 style="text-align=center">Test</h3>
    <p></p>
    <div class="close-button">
      <button type="button" class="right" onclick="closePopup()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Mister Jojo. It works. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: `on*` handlers like `onclick` is the most destructive and bug-prone way of assigning event handlers. Use the [Element.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method instead.

Comment: Also, avoid the use of `style` in JS (unless when really necessary). Use `Element.classList` instead, with its designated methods like `.toggle()` `.remove()` `.add()` and use CSS to define your class styles like `.is-hidden {display: none;}`

Comment: `event.target == modal` is the wrong way to get the actual event's element listener. `Event.currentTarget` should be used, or `Event.target.closest("selector")` in the case of dynamic event delegation.

Comment: `elem.innerText` is not the jQuery's equivalent of `.text()` (which BTW has a silent error handling) - you should rather use `.textContent` instead or `.innerText` - or as already said, jQuery's `.text()`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan my answer just has the ambition to "get the OP's code back on his track". For me too: everything is "out of logic" in the OP's code, first of all the non-use of a `<dialog>` element and related JS methods.

Comment: @Dazzler see also for better codding : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67142639/toggle-modal-popup-from-different-buttons/76901041#76901041

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan and MisterJojo - Thank you guys, for the feedback. I am just starting in JavaScript, and the above feedback is really useful and will apply those changes to improve my code.